Zod - issues added in superRefine do not pass through custom error map
I'm having troubles with Zod schema custom validations using superRefine(). I have a custom global error map, but the issues which come from the superRefine validation do not pass through the error map.
I tried a "local" error map in the parse() function, but with the same result.
I want to use the custom error map to customize my error messages in one place. Is there a way to get the superRefine issues to pass through the error map?
Here is a code example where this can be observed: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/relaxed-rosalind-kctqg3?file=%2Findex.js
The standard validation (min(3)) is visible in the global error map, the "local" parse error map and in the catch also. But the custom validation is not visible in the error maps.
